# Objects not being released in Objective-C++ with ARC

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, objective-c++

I'm seeing a difference in behavior when creating objects in an Objective-C++ class.

If I create an `NSDictionary` containing `NSNumber` objects using dictionaryWith and numberWith, then the objects never get released.  If I create them using `alloc` and `initWith`, then they get cleaned up just fine.

I'm not seeing this in an Objective-C class in the same project.  The project has ARC enabled.  I'm using the Allocations profiling tool in Xcode 4.5.2, looking at the "# Living" value of `CFNumber` and __`NSDictionaryl`.

```
// These objects will NOT be released.
NSDictionary* dict1 = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
  [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInt:val1], @"val1",
  [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInt:val2], @"val2",
  [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInt:val3], @"val3",
  nil];    
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
  postNotificationName:KEY_NET_STATS_VIEW_UDATE object:nil userInfo:dict1];
});

// These objects *will* be released.
NSDictionary* dict2 = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
  [[NSNumber alloc] initWithUnsignedInt:val1], @"val1",
  [[NSNumber alloc] initWithUnsignedInt:val2], @"val2",
  [[NSNumber alloc] initWithUnsignedInt:val3], @"val3",
  nil];    
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
  postNotificationName:KEY_NET_STATS_VIEW_UDATE object:nil userInfo:dict2];
});
```

It's no problem for me to write my code using alloc/initWith but I'd like to understand why the difference.  Everything I've read says they should be equivalent under ARC.

Stack trace of when this code gets called.  All of the below is C++, BTW.

```
#0  0x001fbbe4 in ItRtpSessionManageriOS::OnItRtpOutgoingStatsUpdate(ItRtpSession&, ItRtpSessionManager::ItRtpStats const&)  
#1  0x0007018a in CSceApp::OnItRtpOutgoingStatsUpdate(ItRtpSession&, ItRtpSessionManager::ItRtpStats const&)  
#2  0x0006b808 in ItRtpSession::CallStatsUpdateCallback(ItRtpSessionManager::ItRtpStats const&)  
#3  0x0006ab1e in ItRtpSessionSharedCommXYZ::UpdateOutgoingStats(unsigned long, unsigned long)  
#4  0x0006a958 in ItRtpSessionSharedCommXYZ::Update(unsigned int, unsigned int)  
#5  0x000764ca in CSceApp::EvTimerServiceMgrAwaken(bool, unsigned int, void*)  
#6  0x00076908 in non-virtual thunk to CSceApp::EvTimerServiceMgrAwaken(bool, unsigned int, void*)  
#7  0x002a0134 in xyz::CServicingThread::Activate(unsigned long long, bool*)   
#8  0x0029fb98 in xyz::CServicingThread::Behavior()  
#9  0x0029fc34 in non-virtual thunk to xyz::CServicingThread::Behavior()  
#10 0x002578de in xyz::CAliveObj::StartMechanism(void*)  
#11 0x00259f9e in xyz::CThread::ThreadEntry(void*)  
#12 0x348b5310 in _pthread_start ()  
#13 0x348b51d8 in thread_start ()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under ARC, there are two mechanisms for utilising autorelease pools - as part of the runloop and tied to scope using @autoreleasepool.  The pool is only drained at the end of the runloop, in the first case, or when the autorelease pool goes out of scope, in the second.

So, if you're not letting the runloop run, anything you put there won't be drained.  Likewise if you're using @autoreleasepool somewhere but aren't exiting that scope - perhaps you're sitting in a tight loop somewhere, or blocking inside the scope - then you won't see the pool drain.

Given that, you should look at your code to see if that is what's happening.  Unfortunately unless you post more of your code, we won't be able to help you pinpoint the problem.

Comment: This code is not in a loop and does not block.  If I create and use the objects in an @autoreleasepool block then they get released (the pool drains).  Or if I use alloc/init instead of class methods then the pool drains.  Accepting this answer because it got me trying more things.  I can't say I completely understand the behavior but I have to move on.  Thanks

Comment: If you set a breakpoint in your code and posted the stacktrace here, it might provide a hint.  Perhaps whatever code you're sitting atop is doing something strange.

Comment: Right, so, the key factor here is that you're using a non-Cocoa thread.  Most likely the problem is that nothing in that callstack is setting up an autorelease pool at all, so anything you autorelease just leaks.  You should see error messages about this in your app's stderr or console output.  If not, it could be that something *is* setting up an autorelease pool, but never draining it.  You would have to look at the documentation (or implementation) of the code.  In particular I'd look at your xyz library - that'd be the logical place for it, if anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

When you use an `init...` method with ARC, a `release` call will be inserted after the last reference to that object at compile time. If you don't reference `dict2` in that block after initialization, it will be compiled like the code below pre-ARC:

```
NSNumber *n1 = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithUnsignedInt:val1];
NSNumber *n2 = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithUnsignedInt:val2];
NSNumber *n3 = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithUnsignedInt:val3];
NSDictionary* dict2 = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
  n1, @"val1",
  n2, @"val2",
  n3, @"val3",
  nil];
[n1 release];
[n2 release];
[n3 release];
[dict2 release];
```

(You need to hold a strong reference to it, if you want to keep it)

In comparison, when you use class methods like `dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:`, you'll (usually) get an autoreleased object. It will be released at the end of the run loop. If you log the autoreleased dictionary just after creating it, it will still be around and valid.

Comment: Thanks @DrummerB  The problem is that the objects created with class methods are *not* getting autoreleased.  I didn't show all my code.  After creating the dictionary I use it in a NSNotificationCanter post.  Also, why the difference between Objective-C and Objective-C++?

Comment: @DrummerB: ARC is actually smart enough to be able to "capture" the autoreleased objects returned from class methods in many cases, such that they don't enter the autorelease pool.

Comment: @KevinBallard That's why I said "usually"? Or should that be rather "sometimes"?